# How to get user meta value in wordpress

Tags: user-meta, users

I have created a custom usermeta field named "designation" and fetched all its meta value in loop but it shows duplicates and empty values. I have tried to resolve by using array_unique() function but it does not work. Please guide me how can remove duplicates and blank values.

```
 $args = array(
 'role' => 'subscriber',
 'meta_key' => 'user_designation'
        );

  // The Query  
  $design = array_unique($args);        
  $user_query = new WP_User_Query($design);

  // User Loop
  if ( !empty($user_query->results) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    ?>
    <option><?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_designation', true); ?></option>
    <?php
    }
   }
   else {?>
        <option value="0">No Category Found</option>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the user meta in a variable and check if the variable is empty or not, like below-

```
$args = array(
    'role' => 'subscriber',
    'meta_key' => 'user_designation'
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
// User Loop
$u_meta_array = array();
if ( !empty($user_query->results) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        $u_meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_designation', true);
        if (!empty($u_meta)){
            $u_meta_array[] = $u_meta;
        }
    }
    $u_meta_array_unique = array_unique($u_meta_array);
    foreach ($u_meta_array_unique as $u ) {
        echo '<option>' . $u . '</option>';
    }
} else { ?>
    <option value="0">No Category Found</option>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope that thing is gonna work. Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you so much it works for removing empty values but my another issue is still please let me know where i use `array_unique()` function to remove duplicates meta value

Comment: I don't think you need to use `array_unique()` any more here. It's already pretty fine I think.  If this post helps you then please accept the answer. It would be very helpful. @Yajuvendra

Comment: but there are shows duplicates value. so how can remove it

Comment: No. I don't think there is any duplicate value. It's actually I think same value for different users. Better you do a `print_r()` and attach those value to you question. So we can be sure that is duplicate or same value for different users. @Yajuvendra

Comment: here is the my website [link] (http://www.pronetworker.com/people) please find out the select drop down option under **Search People by Designation**

Comment: Yea. I understood. I'm kinda busy right now. Give me some time. Hopefully I'm gonna be free after 2 hours and then I'll update the answer. Ok?

Comment: @Yajuvendra, Try the updated answer. It would work as you wanted.

Comment: I have implemented your updated answer in my website and all duplicated value were removed but when we try to select option value it will post only last value named **Retail**

Comment: See the value of options in your `select` menu. All are `retail`. Some of your code is manipulating the `select` menu. Check your other codes.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake